# Django: Where to place an infinite loop

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am currently working on a project where I'd need to integrate a django application with mastodon, a federated twitter-like service.

In order to interact with Mastodon, I use Mastodon.py package: https://mastodonpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#

I would need to monitor events occurring to a specific mastodon account, a bot account managed by the django application, using the streaming capabilities provided by the package: https://mastodonpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#streaming

So I would need to call one of these stream methods in an infinite loop. But I can't figure out where I should place it in django. Is there a main loop somewhere where I could insert it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to run this kind of things in the background. There are many options you can choose from to setup background processing.

I find the following quite easy to set up and it might be a good start for you.

[Django Background tasks](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Basically you create a function/job which should be done in background. You annotate it with special decorator to register as a task.

You can then choose when to run - in your case -  you can run it repeatedly every certain amount of time ( no need for "infinite" loop  in your job task).

It is database backend task queue - so you will run a process which monitors your tasks and run them in chosen times. See docs for detail.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Indeed that looks promising. I'll review the doc in more details to check if that work for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can create a django command，place your infinite loop in there, and let supervisor handle the daemonization

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to process whatever you want and call that method in files such as `urls.py`(which will get called only once when the server starts).

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't have thought about this. I'll give it a try but  I wonder if placing an infinite loop here isn't going to block django from running normally.

Comment: Sure it will. This is not a way to do it. Check my suggested answer

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loops are not really recommended when working at Django,but, if you cannot make it work with a method ,a good solution would be to create a seperate thread and run your infinite loop there.

This way the Django application will keep being active and non-blocked and you will have the loop running and waiting for an event.

I honestly don't know if performance and speed wise this is a good solution but it does the job.

Comment: I was thinking about a separate thread, but I don't have any experience working with threaded application. I'll start first with the solution suggested by Enthusiast Martin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58764475/12197595

Comment: Tasks are also a good way to go. 
If you want to read the basics of Threading in Python here is a link with simple examples https://www.simplifiedpython.net/python-threading-example/